# Would it be wise to put a Linux OS on a Mac?

Tags: linux, macintosh

Has anyone tried this either using bootcamp, a VM, or replacing the OS X? Google search yields old info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run several different OSes on my iMac via Parallels Desktop. It worked, but was annoyingly slow and the older version (3) of Parallels I have didn't support SMP. VirtualBox seemed to be faster and free.

Bootcamp isn't virtualisation, it's directly running on bare hardware, so it's faster. But as of version 4, only Windows 7 is officially supported. Not to say other version won't work, but if you need proper support you're out of luck.

If you have a Mac and just want to play with Linux, I'd suggest a VM. If you *need* Linux and no longer need OS X, I'd suggest a PC because it'd give you a better bang for buck ratio and Macs have decent resale value.

Oh and if you do use another OS on a Mac, my tip is get a PC keyboard. Saves hassle.

Answer (score 2):

I dunno about *wise*, but you *can*. I run Fedora on a 27" iMac, and it's a great hardware platform for it. At first, I dual booted using [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/), but now I've ditched OS X entirely and just run Linux as the only OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And how does it work? Same speed? Slower?

Comment: It works like Linux on Intel hardware, which is to say very well. I haven't done any benchmarks.